# Active Directory Groups With SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, active-directory, ldap

Alright, so I already have an existing connection to Active Directory on my server.  I know that querying active directory works.  What I want to be able to do is query for all of the ou's and/or groups in active directory, and also be able to find the users the belong to those groups/ous.

this is the current query that just pulls user information (or part of a stored procedure set up to pull all users):

```
SELECT
    userAccountControl,
    DisplayName AS [NAME],
    givenName AS FIRSTNAME,
    middleName, 
    sn AS LASTNAME,
    employeeID AS EMPID,
    telephoneNumber AS EXT,
    Title, 
    Department AS DEPT,
    Division,
    sAMAccountName AS UserName,
    mail AS Email,
    homeDirectory AS HomeDir,
    userPrincipalName AS LOGON,
    manager
FROM         OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
                      '
 select
     userAccountControl,
     DisplayName,
     givenName,
     middleName,
     sn,
     employeeID,
     telephoneNumber,
     Title,
     Department,
     Division,
     sAMAccountName,
     mail,
     homeDirectory,
     userPrincipalName,
     manager
 from ''LDAP://name''
 where sn > ''a''
    and sn <''h''
 order by DisplayName
 ')
AS derivedtbl_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of the fact that you cannot query more objects than the AD server is willing to return in one reply?

The ADSI SQL provider does not support paging through the results. The AD server is usually configured to return the first 1000 results only.

If you query for virtually all AD objects at once you are very likely to hit that limit.

Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: "this is the current query that just pulls user information (or part of a stored procedure set up to pull all users):"
the sp this is from has 5 insert/select statements that go into a temp table which then is compared to a table on our data warehouse db and updates the table

Comment: basically our ad has several different groups, IT, QA, Document Control, etc.  I want to be able to see what groups there are in ad and what users belong to which group.

Comment: I don't think SQL is quite the right tool for finding out about group memberships or mapping all users in the directory to a table. I'd recommend using a programming layer between AD and database and not using SQL to query the AD. It's possible (and tempting) but may prove more painful than useful down the road.